# getting a reference binding to misaligned address error for LeetCode problem Max Frequency Stack

Tags: c++

So the problem says to implement a max frequency stack which will always pop the max frequency element, and if same frequency, the one which is closest to top will be popped. Now i tried implementing a map of stacks where each frequency count was mapped to a stack containing elements with that frequency.

The main problem i am facing is this error:

Line 157: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_deque.h:162:16

Test case which fails:

```
["FreqStack","push","push","push","push","push","push","pop","push","pop","push","pop","push","pop","push","pop","pop","pop","pop","pop","pop"]


[[],[4],[0],[9],[3],[4],[2],[],[6],[],[1],[],[1],[],[4],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

I am unable to understand the reason for this. I have searched other asked questions on SO, and the error seems to be due to uninitialised variables or out of bounds access. But i dont really seem to find where this problem occurs in my code.

Here is my code:

```
class FreqStack {
public:
    
    unordered_map<int,int>freq;
    unordered_map<int,stack<int>>st;
    int maxfreq=0;
    FreqStack() {
        
        
    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        maxfreq=max(maxfreq,++freq[x]);
        st[freq[x]].push(x);    
    }
    
    int pop() {
       if(st[maxfreq].size()==0)
           maxfreq--;
       int t=st[maxfreq].top();
        st[maxfreq].pop();
        return t;
    }
};

/*
 * Your FreqStack object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * FreqStack* obj = new FreqStack();
 * obj->push(x);
 * int param_2 = obj->pop();
 */
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :D

Comment: I wouldn't mind betting that `maxfreq` is going negative in your `pop` routine. Easy thing to add a check for.

Comment: ok so i checked the code both logically and using compiler but that does not seem to be the case. Also the maxfreq will go negative only and only if pop() command is called on empty stack which LC says will not happen. Also why the downvote??

Comment: Well I didn't give you the down vote but I imagine it was because we like to see some data with this kind of problem. If you can supply some data that reproduces the problem then it should be easy to solve, without that it's very hard.

Comment: test case added

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm you are attempting but the failure is clear enough. In the line `int t=st[maxfreq].top();` the stack is sometimes empty and this causes the failure you see. I was able to simplify the test case, the following sequence produces the same error `push(4), push(4), pop(), push(4), pop(), pop()`.

Comment: Thanku, a simple change solved my problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

### Looks pretty good!

Just in the `pop()`, we can simply save the `top` first, then we would `stack.pop()` and decrement (if stack is not empty) and then return the `top`:

```
// This block might trivially optimize the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct FreqStack {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    FreqStack() {}
    std::unordered_map<SizeType, SizeType> frequencies;
    std::unordered_map<SizeType, std::stack<SizeType>> mapstack;
    SizeType max_fr = 0;

    const void push(const int x) {
        max_fr = std::max(max_fr, ++frequencies[x]);
        mapstack[frequencies[x]].push(x);
    }


    const int pop() {
        const auto& top = mapstack[max_fr].top();
        mapstack[max_fr].pop();

        if (mapstack[frequencies[top]--].empty()) {
            --max_fr;
        }

        return top;
    }

};
```